# Can Tomcat 7 be configured to insert "Content-Security-Policy" HTTP header?

Tags: http, security, tomcat7, content-security-policy

Can Tomcat 7 be configured to insert `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'` HTTP header with every response, like it can insert other security related headers, for example `X-Frame-Options`?

Answer (score 15):

Once it cannot be achieved with [Tomcat 7.x built in filters](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html), you could try one of the following options:

### Creating a filter in your application

If adding a filter to your application is an option, you could use the following code to add a header to every response:

```java
@WebFilter("/*")
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'self'");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

### Creating a custom valve in your Tomcat

Another option is a custom valve. Quoting the steps from this [page](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.ie/2012/12/tomcat-7-custom-valve.html):

> 1. Create a Maven Java Application.
> 2. Add the following dependency:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupid>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
>     <artifactid>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
>     <version>7.0.34</version>
>     <scope>provided</scope>
>  </dependency>
> ```
>
> 3. Create your Java class and extend it from [`ValveBase`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/ValveBase.html).
> 4. Implement the [`invoke(Request, Response)`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/ValveBase.html#invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request,%20org.apache.catalina.connector.Response)) method.
> 5. Build your library (`.jar`) file
> 6. Install the library in the `${tomcat.home}/lib` directory.
> 7. Configure the `server.xml` to use your new valve. For example:
>
> ```
> <valve className="com.example.MyValve"/>
> ```
>
> 8. Start the server to see your new valve in action

Your valve implementation could be like:

```java
public class MyValve extends ValveBase {

    @Override
    public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, 
                                                                  ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = response.getResponse();
        httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'self'");

        getNext().invoke(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I should have mentioned "without code change".

Comment: @PeterKlimczak I think a custom valve can do the trick. I'll update my answer.