# Apache and Tomcat Integration

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets, iframe

I'm fairly new with Apache and Tomcat, so try to explain me the better you know :P **I'm only working in local**.

I have one application that needs Tomcat to execute Servlets, so I can type:

http://localhost:8080/rrcapp/xservlet?consult=list01

That works. I also have my webpage running with Apache 2.4, so I can type:

http://localhost:80/websrv/index.htm

That works too. The problem comes when in my index.htm serving in Apache, make a call in an Iframe with Chrome, to that Servlet, getting the error:

```
Refused to display ...in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

I've read about setting in my httpd.conf to unset x-frame-options or setting with ALLOW-FROM but it seems just doesn't work with Chrome.

Then, I've read about CSP policies, but I cannot figure out how to set this kind of policy in mi httpd.conf so I can run servlets inside the iframe, inside my Apache server.

Can anyone help me with this?

Regards :)

***EDIT 1:***

Thanks Eddie James Carswell II  I understood the error came from the Tomcat. I've read the document he showed me, and tried to configure my web.xml inside my /conf dir in Tomcat, this is the result:

```js
    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  
  <init-param>
   <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  
  <init-param>
   <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
   <param-value>ALLOW-FROM</param-value>
  </init-param>
  
  <init-param>
   <param-name>antiClickJackingUri</param-name>
   <param-value>http://localhost:80/*</param-value>
  </init-param>
    </filter>
 
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I restarted the Tomcat server and tried again to load the Iframe and got another error:

```
Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'http://localhost:8080/rrcapp/xservlet?consult=list01': 'ALLOW-FROM http://localhost:80/*' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.
```

***EDIT 2:***

It seems it works on the most recent version of Firefox (57.0 Quantum) as well in IE 10 and EDGE. Still, it doesnt work with Chrome :P

Maybe ALLOW-FROM has some problems with Chrome, but if I'm not wrong, I cannot establish CSP directives in Tomcat. How can I resolve this on Chrome?

Any help here? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: For the X-Frame-Options header in particular, you might have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options for a decent explanation. Changing the Apache config wouldn't affect the HTTP headers sent along with the content of the iframe, since they're coming directly from Tomcat. Since the header is being set by Tomcat, you'll have to modify it there. You might also consider reverse proxying the Tomcat instance, which would allow you to intercept and modify the HTTP headers sent with the data, and would allow you to serve your content on port 80 as a bonus.

Comment: So, do you think that error is thrown by the Tomcat? Since I'm in Chrome and besides that, the X-Frame-Options (ALLOW FROM) doesn work with this browser. Where should I modify Tomcat to allow this kind of calls? Many thanks.

Comment: This might be useful: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#HTTP_Header_Security_Filter I'd also recommend checking the Apache vhost configs and everything under `conf-enabled` to ensure the header isn't being snuck in somewhere.

Comment: I'll try to read the text you told me, thanks.

Comment: Now I'm at work, but tonight I'll try to change some things here and there, I've been reading that Apache and Tomcat can coexist, and like I said, they work fine. The problem is when in Chrome, I try to make a calla to a servlet inside an iframe, obtaining the error described.

Comment: I didnt get the key to achieve what I asked for :) Some more ideas?

Comment: The Chrome problem with the X-Frame-Options `ALLOW-FROM` directive is a known issue, see [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94836).
The current recommendation is to use [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) and use the [`frame-ancenstors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) directive. I can provide more info on that, if needed.

Comment: Also, to address the no CSP in tomcat bit, it is possible, just not with the built-in filters. Perhaps one of the methods discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37306300) may be of help.

Comment: Eddie, as always, thanks for those tips. 

Maybe  I'm complicating the things a lot. Since I'm working in local, maybe I should try the same goal, but with ReverseProxy?

Comment: Using Apache as a [reverse proxy](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TomcatReverseProxy) for Tomcat would probably be the best solution. A few `ProxyPass` directives in a new (or existing) `VirtualHost` could accomplish this. Not only would it allow you to strip or modify any headers Tomcat sends, you could even host them both from the same origin and remove this problem entirely. This would also allow you to serve everything on port 80 (or 443) instead of using 8080. Whether you choose to serve the app from a subdirectory or subdomain would be up to you.

Comment: See also: https://rvdb.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/reverse-proxying-tomcat-webapps-behind-apache/

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I want to thanks to Eddie James Carswell II, who assisted me with this issue all the time, giving me very valuable tips.

Finally, I got it with Proxys via httpd. As stated in the article linked, uncommenting this lines:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

And then configuring my app directory in Apache:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /rrcapp http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /rrcapp http://localhost:8080

<Location "/rrcapp">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

Now, I can write in a JS call,. Example:

```
document.location = '/rrcapp/xservlet?consult=list01';
```

And access to my apps resources, located in Tomcat.

Why this solution? Its universal in every browser, and easy to configure.

Why not the other one? It worked on the most recent version of Firefox (57.0 Quantum) as well in IE 10 and EDGE. Still, it didn't work with Chromem, wich is the browser I use. The configuration anyways set up, was this in the web.xml in Tomcat directory.

```js
    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  
  <init-param>
   <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  
  <init-param>
   <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
   <param-value>ALLOW-FROM</param-value>
  </init-param>
  
  <init-param>
   <param-name>antiClickJackingUri</param-name>
   <param-value>http://localhost:80/*</param-value>
  </init-param>
    </filter>
 
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Hope this helps in the future :)

Thanks Eddie!

Comment: If Chrome is still giving you grief about `ALLOW-FROM`, you can just change it back to `SAMEORIGIN`, since you're now serving everything from the same origin anyway. Or if you wanted to do away with `X-Frame-Options` entirely, which I don't exactly recommend, you can add `header unset X-Frame-Options` to your vhost config. Either method should fix the Chrome issue.